# Pulling data from one entity onto an Email form within a Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I have a workflow that will fire once a form field changes.  The workflow checks the value and then sends an email if one particular value is selected.  That much I've managed to figure out.

Now I need to pull a field value from a separate entity to populate the "to" field of the email.  We have a Configuration entity that stores the value of a distribution list - we want to pull this into the email that the workflow generates.

I've created an N<>1 relationship between the primary entity and the Configuration entity, however I only see the Entity and not the entity's Fields in the email form assistant.  Any idea how I can pull that data onto the email form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the entity populated under "Look for" and then in the drop down under that you see no values? I'm guessing in your configuration entity your email address you want to use for the email recipient is a text field. In order for the form assistant to populate the second drop down, the field types must match up - or in this case for a field to show up as useable for the "To" field, it needs to be an Account, Contact, User, etc... values you can send an email to.

My suggestion is create a Contact record that has the proper email address and either relate that to your base entity in place of your configuration entity (if possible) or relate your configuration entity to Contact and populate the new lookup on the configuration entity accordingly.